# How can I turn my top menu bar and all the window bars dark?

Tags: macos, desktop, settings, menu-bar

Is there a way to invert the colors on the menu bar at the top of the screen, as well as the title bars of all the windows is OS X? I have a lot of Terminals open usually, and the the light menu bar stands in the way of the vibe I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [**Obsidian Menu Bar**](http://www.obsidianmenubar.com):

[image]

> #### Obsidian Menu Bar
>
> A hack that makes your OS X menu bar black. And yes, it blends.
>   Ready for 10.9.2!

Answer (score 3):

With OS X Yosemite, you can change a setting in System Preferences so that the menu bar and Dock appear dark.

Go to **System Preferences** → **General** and check **Use dark menu bar and Dock**.

[image: Use dark menu bar and Dock]

The menu bar looks like this when in Dark Mode:

[image: Dark menu bar]

The Dock looks like this when in Dark Mode:

[image: Dark Dock]

Comment: https://github.com/nirbhayg/Flick/releases

Comment: This option seems to no longer exist in Catalina 10.15.4, but the terminal command worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a hidden preference for using a black menu bar in full screen:

```
defaults write -g NSFullScreenDarkMenu -bool true
```

[image]

It only affects full screen windows though. Some menu extras and status menus don't have graphics for a black background:

[image]

Comment: Works in Catalina!